# ReSharper always asks to change System.Action to System.Action<T>

Tags: c#, resharper

**Using VS2010 and ReSharper 5**

I have a method which returns a System.Action

```
private Action ExtractFile()
{
    return delegate
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    };
}
```

ReSharper, for some reason, tends to show me a correction that the return type of the method should be mapped to `System.Action<T>` or one of its variants. It seems that it won't recognize the non-generic version! VS complies and doesn't complain about this!

When I mouse over the red curly line, the tooltip shown says

> Incorrect number of type parameters.
>   Candidates are:    void  System.Action(T)
>   void System.Action(T1, T2)   ...
>   *... and the list continues until T1-T16*

Any ideas?[image: See the return type highlighted by ReSharper]

Comment: Same here. Please show the code inside the delegate.

Comment: @Daniel: Inside the delegate, I have a call to SaveFileDialog, which I need to build further. But I don't think that can cause the problem. To confirm, I just added a MessageBox.Show("Test"); but ReSharper still complains as if it is an error. VS can build and execute this without any problems.

Comment: Please show some real code that reproduces the problem. It is obviously no problem that occurs under all circumstances as we can't reproduce it.

Comment: I wonder if it's because it's an instance method and therefore it's suggesting that a class instance should ideally be passed to it?  I dunno - just a guess!

Comment: Still not reproducible. What version of VS and Resharper are you using?

Comment: @Daniel: VS2010 and ReSharper 5

Comment: I have had a strange problem in the past with ReSharper 5 and VS2008: After opening a large solution in VS with "Check errors in whole solution" enabled, it would show arbitrary errors, but the code compiled just fine as in your case. After deleting the ReSharper files from the harddisk for that project, disabling "Check errors in whole solution" and re-enabling it, ReSharper again recognized everything just fine and showed no errors.

Comment: @Daniel: I think, I'll try that as well and will post my results!

Comment: Do that. Important: I didn't close VS before or after deleting the files. In fact, the error reappeared every time I restarted VS.

Comment: @Daniel: Did all of what you said, and also un-installed then re-installed ReSharper. No luck :-( Looks like I have got to live with this!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe the ReSharper support can help.

Comment: I do not have ReSharper to test this, but have you tried to change the `delegate` to `delegate()`?

Comment: @mgronber: With your suggestion, ReSharper complains about using a lambda syntax instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you need to update ReSharper to the latest version, which is version 5.1. If you have items that are not loaded by ReSharper (i.e., check your excluded items list), then it will mark them as unknown, even if your code is legal and references the items.

You may try Clear Cache, or reset default settings.

Your screenshot did not show a curly line under "delegate", but with default settings it should suggest you to rewrite the code as follows (but this is not necessarily better):

```
private Action ExtractFile()
{
    return () => MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

If all fails, click the little lightbulb on the left (or hit Alt+Enter). Select "Inspection options for ..." and change the severity or select ignore.

Comment: I did perform "Clear Cache" and later a complete re-install of ReSharper. To ensure that every setting I had customized is restored back to original (default). No luck yet.

Comment: Thanks for the RS update suggestion, that did the trick! It is not annoying me anymore with the red curly underline! +1 vote and marked as answer!